# Real time website visitor tracking system

Tags: javascript, web, analytics, node.js, traffic

I want to develop an application that allows me to track website visitors. I'm exploring node.js now as an alternative for this. This system will have 3 parts:

1. Server side script, probably a node.js server.
2. Air application would be the client. It will connect to the node.js server and display the users online.
3. Javascript code, the tracking code that will be on each page of the site.

Has someone experimented with something like this? Any ideas, comments, recommendations will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at:

- [Hummingbird](http://projects.nuttnet.net/hummingbird/) on node.js.
- [Where is waldo](http://github.com/technoweenie/wheres-waldo) on node.js

Why Air?

Comment: why not air? I'm thinking on a desktop widget, cross-platform, that you can have always open and se what's going on on the website.

Comment: Is the Hummingbird deprecated? The last checkin was 2 years ago and the links are not working.